# Opera browser. Strange 0-9 keyboard

Tags: windows-7, browser, opera-11

The Opera browser is one of the best out there. It's the only mainstream browser with **1-KEY TAB CYCLING**. None of thet Ctrl+Tab stuff. Just hit **1** to cycle left and **2** to cycle right. In any case, I am having an ongoing issue with my opera browser, when I have multiple tabs open.

If I have multiple tabs open for a long time, after a while of being idle, the browser goes into some strange mode. This mode is not visually detectable. At the most, I think it occurs after a webpage refresh, which happens periodically anyway. After some random refresh, then ALL of my keys become 0-9 keys. Meaning even if I hit a letter key all I get is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 in ascending order cycling back to 0 again. Also, if I hold shift, then it will cycle the symbols of the 0-9 keys on your qwerty keyboard.

The only way beyond closing my browser I've found to end this "mode" is to get a browser menu to popup. Hitting Ctrl-O to Open something, then Escaping that menu ends the 0-9 key mode.

Does anyone know what is happening, and how to keep my browser from switching into that mode?

This happens on the latest version of Opera and it's past 2 updates.

Comment: You're computer has been possessed by the Phantom of the Opera...

Comment: @iglvzx "You are computer has been possessed by the Phantom of the Opera..." funniest part is the misspell.

Comment: @Hawken, Your right. ;) *(Happens to the best of us...)*

Comment: Took me too long to catch it! Funny, though a solution or insight would have been a bit better.

Comment: If applicable, can you update your question to include any browser add-ons or keyboard software (e.g AutoHotkey) that you use? Does pressing the Tab or Escape key do anything when you have this problem?

Comment: Also, which specific version of Opera?

Comment: @iglvzx Yeah right, I would of caught that. ;)

Comment: sorry VISQL but I'm on a mac, so I don't seem to have the NUM key tab switching, so I just use `ctrl` + `tab`

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't think there's an answer to that one. It's a bug.

I myself get a situation where after a period of time none of the tabs are clickable and the only way to change between them is to use ctrl+tab to switch, cmd+w to close tab and cmd+t to open a new one.

Comment: I see. I recently installed the latest Opera Release 11.64 and the problems seems to be gone. My previous version was 11.5 or so.